# Sencha Touch Customize Navigation Bar in navigation view

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, navigationbar

I'm doing a simple app which has a navigation view for containing a list, when you press the list I wanna show some HTML or something, but a "new" window so I can take advantage of the back-button on the navigationbar.

My problem now is that I need a search field on the navigationbar, for the inital showing, the problem is that I don't understand how to modify the navigationbar so it gets a search bar. Here's my code:

```
Ext.define('AppName.view.MainNav', {
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

xtype: 'mainnav',

requires: [
    'Ext.field.Search', 'Ext.TitleBar'
],

config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
        {
        navigationBar: {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            items: [
                { xtype: 'spacer' },
                {
                    xtype: 'searchfield',
                    placeHolder: 'Search...',

                    }
                },
                { xtype: 'spacer' }
            ]
        },

        xtype: 'list',
        fullscreen: true,

        store: {
            fields: ['name', 'number'],
            sorters: 'name',
            data: [
                {name: 'bla', number: 0},
                {name: 'blo', number: 1},
                {name: 'bliblo', number: 2},
                {name: 'Bliblablo', number: 3},
                {name: 'bliboasdas', number: 4},
            ]
        },

        itemTpl: '{name}'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

There is now No search field on the navigationbar, it's just empty. How do I fix? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The navigationBar configuration must be inside the config tag, this code works for me:

```
Ext.define('AppName.view.MainNav', {
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

xtype: 'mainnav',

requires: ['Ext.field.Search', 'Ext.TitleBar'],

config: {
    fullscreen: true,

    navigationBar: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'searchfield',
                placeHolder: 'Search...',
                align: 'right'
            }
        ]
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'test'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            fullscreen: true,

            store: {
                fields: ['name', 'number'],
                sorters: 'name',
                data: [
                    {name: 'bla', number: 0},
                    {name: 'blo', number: 1},
                    {name: 'bliblo', number: 2},
                    {name: 'Bliblablo', number: 3},
                    {name: 'bliboasdas', number: 4},
                ]
            },

            itemTpl: '{name}'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

Comment: The above code dint work for me. I still get an empty navigation bar.